# Finding url change with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, python-requests

I have this URL - 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Aylmer_Fisher' and when I open it with a web browser it changes to 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Fisher' and I need to find the second URL from the first: input Ronaly_Aylmer_Fisher and get Ronald_Fisher.

I tried using requests and urllib.request to find redirect history but it didn't work.
Is there a way to detect this using Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the reason why you can't see the redirects in the requests history  from [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31939570/7832176):

> Requests doesn't show the redirect because you're not actually being
>   redirected in the HTTP sense. Wikipedia does some JavaScript trickery
>   (probably HTML5 history modification and pushState) to change the
>   address that's shown in the address bar, but that doesn't apply to
>   Requests, of course.

If you check the page source
(`view-source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Aylmer_Fisher`), the redirected url is available here:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Fisher"/>
```

You can scrape it using [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) or [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) like this:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Aylmer_Fisher')

# Using regex (not sure if this is the best regex approach)
href_regex = re.compile(r'<link rel="canonical" href="(.*)"/>')
redirected_url = href_regex.search(r.text).groups()[0]

# Using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
redirected_url = soup.find('link', rel='canonical')['href']

print(redirected_url)
```

Output:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Fisher

Or, to get the output you want, you can do this:

```
print(redirected_url.split('/')[-1])
```

Output:

> Ronald_Fisher